# Android animation rotate stucks when calling additional methods

Tags: java, android, animation, java-threads

I want an imageView to be rotating, during my method "fireShowAction" collects some information from the "socket".

This is a snippet of my code:

1st: create a button at "onActivityCreated()" method

```
btnUpdate = (ImageView) mContext.findViewById(R.id.btnRefreshDatum);
btnUpdate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
    if ((etStart.getText().toString() != null) && !etStart.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("")
            && (etEnd.getText().toString() != null) && !etEnd.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("")) {

      if (!searchUpdate) {
        searchUpdate = true;

        Animation rotate = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(mContext, R.anim.busy_rotate);
        btnUpdate.startAnimation(rotate);
        fireShowAction();
      }
      else {
        searchUpdate = false;
        btnUpdate.clearAnimation();
      }
    }
  }
});
```

2nd: the method which is beeing called

```
public void fireShowAction() {
Runnable runner = new Runnable() {

  public void run() {
    System.out.println("FireShowAction !!!!!!!!!!!!!");
    Calendar tempStart;
    Calendar tempEnd;
#################
// I´ve reduced this code on the most important
#################
    getDataOfPeriod(tempStart.getTimeInMillis() / 1000, tempEnd.getTimeInMillis() / 1000, key);
    stopAnimation();
  }
};
//    btnToday.post(runner);
runner.run();
}
```

I´ve tried to do the runners work by "onPost()" but this wasn't the solution.

The strangest thing is that my animation is working if I don't call fireShowAction(). If I call it, the animation will stuck until fireShowAction() has done it's work.

I think it's not a big ptoblem I'm searching for... I would be pleased if someone knows a solution.

Thank you guys.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to start a thread instead of a runner.

```
Thread th = new Thread(runner);
th.start();
```

instead of

```
runner.run();
```